Is there a way to prevent pydantic from calling my function used to find config files on import?
My class looks something like this:
class MyConfig(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_file=get_configs(),
    )

I didn't realize that my get_configs() seems to be getting called on import. I discovered this when I had a bug in that function and pytest collection was failing.
Is this a python behavior or something specific to how the model_config attribute of the BaseSettings class works? It doesn't make sense to me because I would expect my get_configs() function to only get called when the code that is actually instantiating MyConfig is executed.

model_config is a class variable, not an instance variable. It gets set when the class is created. This is python behavior.

@Mark do you know if pydantic offers a workaround for this if I only want the config loading code to fire on instantiation?

This is normal python behavior for any class. Python executes the body of the class definition the same as it would execute module level code - accounting for the fact that it is within the class. For instance, at module level, a function definition (e.g. def foo(): return 1), binds the already-compiled function to the name "foo" in the module namespace. In a class definition, a method (e.g., def foo(self): return 1), the function object is bound to "foo" in the class namespace.
In your case, the class level "model_config" is assigned the result of the function call.
